# Phoronix-test-suite: gzip-decompress fails to download needed file

Tags: gzip, performance-testing, benchmarking

I am trying to download `pts/system-decompress-gzip-1.1.0` but during installation I receive the following message:

```
Phoronix Test Suite v6.6.0

To Install: pts/system-decompress-gzip-1.1.0

Determining File Requirements .........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Searching Download Caches .............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

1 Test To Install
    1 File To Download [219MB]

pts/system-decompress-gzip-1.1.0:
    Test Installation 1 of 1
    1 File Needed [219 MB / 4 Minutes]
    Downloading: qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                                                                      [219MB]
    Estimated Download Time: 4m .......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
        Checksum Failed: http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0.tar.gz
Try downloading the file again (Y/n):
```

I tried to install `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0.tar.gz` by myself but the installation failed. Obviously the above url is broken and I am wondering if there is a configuration file I can change with a working link.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out at

> /var/lib/phoronix-test-suite/test-profiles/pts/system-decompress-gzip-1.1.0#

there is a `download.xml` file which I replaced the link! Now it works!